# Spring autowiring not working in Vaadin 7 UI

Tags: spring, vaadin, vaadin7, spring-4

I have a Vaadin 7 project. It's works. Now I need to implement Hibernate 4 to access Database and I want to use also Spring 4 to use its annotations.

The problem is that the autowired annotation doesn't work. The related object is always null.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>bermacorp</groupId>
    <artifactId>b-sci</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>b-sci</name>

    <properties>
        <vaadin.version>7.6.1</vaadin.version>
        <vaadin.plugin.version>${vaadin.version}</vaadin.plugin.version>
        <jetty.plugin.version>9.2.3.v20140905</jetty.plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

        <spring.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <version.hibernate>4.3.6.Final</version.hibernate>
        <version.slf4j>1.5.8</version.slf4j>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-addons</id>
            <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiler</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>19.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${version.hibernate}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${version.slf4j}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>8.4-702.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/gwt-unitCache/**,
                        WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets/WEB-INF/**</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
                    <webappDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets</webappDirectory>
                    <draftCompile>false</draftCompile>
                    <compileReport>false</compileReport>
                    <style>OBF</style>
                    <strict>true</strict>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>update-theme</goal>
                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/styles.css</include>
                                <include>**/styles.scss.cache</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            vaadin-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[7.1.11,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>resources</goal>
                                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                            <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                                            <goal>update-theme</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>vaadin-prerelease</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>

            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
                    <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
                    <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>b-sci</display-name>

  <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Bsci</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>bsci.BsciServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>UI</param-name>
            <param-value>bsci.BsciUI</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Bsci</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location = "classpath:application.properties"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${hibernate.generate_statistics}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>bsci.entity</value>
            </list>
        </property>

    </bean>

   <bean id="transactionManager"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <context:annotation-config />
    <tx:annotation-driven/>

   <context:component-scan base-package="bsci.dao"/>

   <bean class="bsci.service.impl.ServizioImpl" id="servizio"/>
</beans>
```

BsciServlet.java

```
package bsci;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AutowireCapableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils;

import com.vaadin.server.ServiceException;
import com.vaadin.server.SessionInitEvent;
import com.vaadin.server.SessionInitListener;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BsciServlet extends VaadinServlet implements SessionInitListener {

    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);

        try {
            this.webApplicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(config.getServletContext());
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            throw new ServletException("could not locate containing WebApplicationContext");
        }

        AutowireCapableBeanFactory ctx = getWebApplicationContext().getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();

        ctx.autowireBean(this);
    }

    protected final AutowireCapableBeanFactory getAutowireCapableBeanFactory() throws ServletException {
        try {
            return getWebApplicationContext().getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            throw new ServletException("containing context " + getWebApplicationContext() + " is not autowire-capable", e);
        }
    }

    protected final WebApplicationContext getWebApplicationContext() throws ServletException {
        if (this.webApplicationContext == null) {
            throw new ServletException("can't retrieve WebApplicationContext before init() is invoked");
        }
        return this.webApplicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionInit(SessionInitEvent event) throws ServiceException {
    }

    @Override
    protected final void servletInitialized() throws ServletException {
        super.servletInitialized();
        getService().addSessionInitListener(this);
        getService().addSessionInitListener(new BsciSessionInitListener());
    }
}
```

BsciSessionInitListener.java

```
package bsci;

import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

import com.vaadin.server.BootstrapFragmentResponse;
import com.vaadin.server.BootstrapListener;
import com.vaadin.server.BootstrapPageResponse;
import com.vaadin.server.ServiceException;
import com.vaadin.server.SessionInitEvent;
import com.vaadin.server.SessionInitListener;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BsciSessionInitListener implements SessionInitListener {

    @Override
    public final void sessionInit(final SessionInitEvent event)
            throws ServiceException {

        event.getSession().addBootstrapListener(new BootstrapListener() {

            @Override
            public void modifyBootstrapPage(final BootstrapPageResponse response) {
                final Element head = response.getDocument().head();
                head.appendElement("meta")
                        .attr("name", "viewport")
                        .attr("content",
                                "width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no");
                head.appendElement("meta")
                        .attr("name", "apple-mobile-web-app-capable")
                        .attr("content", "yes");
                head.appendElement("meta")
                        .attr("name", "apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style")
                        .attr("content", "black-translucent");

                String contextPath = response.getRequest().getContextPath();
            }

            @Override
            public void modifyBootstrapFragment(
                    final BootstrapFragmentResponse response) {
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Now in my UI class the autowired object is always null.

```
package bsci;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.google.common.eventbus.Subscribe;
import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.Widgetset;
import com.vaadin.server.Page;
import com.vaadin.server.Page.BrowserWindowResizeEvent;
import com.vaadin.server.Page.BrowserWindowResizeListener;
import com.vaadin.server.Responsive;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinSession;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.Window;
import com.vaadin.ui.themes.ValoTheme;

import bsci.data.DataProvider;
import bsci.data.DummyDataProvider;
import bsci.entity.Utente;
import bsci.event.BsciEvent.BrowserResizeEvent;
import bsci.event.BsciEvent.CloseOpenWindowsEvent;
import bsci.event.BsciEvent.UserLoggedOutEvent;
import bsci.event.BsciEvent.UserLoginRequestedEvent;
import bsci.event.BsciEventBus;
import bsci.service.Servizio;
import bsci.view.LoginView;
import bsci.view.MainView;

@Theme("bscitheme")
@Widgetset("bsci.BsciWidgetset")
public final class BsciUI extends UI {

    @Autowired
    Servizio servizio;

    private final DataProvider dataProvider = new DummyDataProvider();
    private final BsciEventBus dashboardEventbus = new BsciEventBus();

    @Override
    protected void init(final VaadinRequest request) {

        BsciEventBus.register(this);
        Responsive.makeResponsive(this);
        addStyleName(ValoTheme.UI_WITH_MENU);

        updateContent();

        Page.getCurrent().addBrowserWindowResizeListener(new BrowserWindowResizeListener() {
            @Override
            public void browserWindowResized(final BrowserWindowResizeEvent event) {
                BsciEventBus.post(new BrowserResizeEvent());
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateContent() {
        Utente user = (Utente) VaadinSession.getCurrent().getAttribute(Utente.class.getName());
        if (user != null) {
            setContent(new MainView());
            removeStyleName("loginview");
            getNavigator().navigateTo(getNavigator().getState());
        } else {
            setContent(new LoginView());
            addStyleName("loginview");
        }
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void userLoginRequested(final UserLoginRequestedEvent event) {
        Utente user = getDataProvider().authenticate(event.getUserName(), event.getPassword());
        VaadinSession.getCurrent().setAttribute(Utente.class.getName(), user);
        updateContent();
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void userLoggedOut(final UserLoggedOutEvent event) {
        VaadinSession.getCurrent().close();
        Page.getCurrent().reload();
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void closeOpenWindows(final CloseOpenWindowsEvent event) {
        for (Window window : getWindows()) {
            window.close();
        }
    }

    public static DataProvider getDataProvider() {
        return ((BsciUI) getCurrent()).dataProvider;
    }

    public static BsciEventBus getDashboardEventbus() {
        return ((BsciUI) getCurrent()).dashboardEventbus;
    }

    public Servizio getServizio() {
        return servizio;
    }
}
```

Can you help me, please?
I don't understand the reason.

Comment: Autowiring happens on beans managed by Spring which your UI is not. I see that you're trying to manually (which seems overkill) use an `AutowireCapeableBeanFactory` but I can't see how it's going to be used to populate the UI fields. If you can use spring boot, take a look at the [official tutorial](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Vaadin+Spring) which makes things easier. Alternatively there are [other add-ons](https://vaadin.com/directory#!browse/search=spring) which integrate Vaadin & Spring, or you could alter a bit your code and provide your own UIProvider that returns spring beans.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you're trying to let Spring inject something into your UI, but Spring doesn't know about your UI.

Use the [Vaadin Spring integration](https://vaadin.com/wiki?p_p_id=36&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=row-1&p_p_col_pos=1&p_p_col_count=3&_36_struts_action=%2Fwiki%2Fview&p_r_p_185834411_nodeName=vaadin.com%20wiki&p_r_p_185834411_title=I%20b%20-%20Getting%20started%20with%20Vaadin%20Spring%20without%20Spring%20Boot) instead of implementing it yourself.  Doing it yourself is possible, but then you need some place where you manually look up some Components in the `WebApplicationContext`, for example the `View` components could be prototype scoped beans looked up in a `ViewProvider` used by the `Navigator`.  But now that we have the official Vaadin Spring integration this isn't necessary anymore.

Comment: I'm trying to follow your advice, but now I receive this message error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope 'vaadin-ui'

I added @ScopeUI to my UI class, changed VaadinServlet to SpringVaadinServlet and update my web.xml. What's the problem?

Comment: Your UI class should have `@SpringUI`.  Other Components that you want to use with a lifecycle equal to the UI should have `@ScopeUI` as well as `@SpringComponent`.  See the example [here](https://vaadin.com/wiki?p_p_id=36&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=row-1&p_p_col_pos=1&p_p_col_count=3&_36_struts_action=%2Fwiki%2Fview&p_r_p_185834411_nodeName=vaadin.com+wiki&p_r_p_185834411_title=II+-+Injection+and+Scopes+with+Vaadin+Spring)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, but I solved the problem using vaadin spring integration add-on

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ru.xpoft.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-vaadin-integration</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Why not the standard `vaadin-spring` addon?

Comment: It seems the author is happy with any working solution, no matter what you said Herman